# MySQL: Searching a single table multiple times?

Tags: mysql, search

I have a table that's holding metadata for entrys from another table. The metadata-table looks like this (I removed relating Ids so it's more obvious):

`id entry_id property value

1 12 color blue

2 12  shape circle

3 13  color red

4 13  shape circle

5 14  color blue

6 14  shape square

7 15  material stone

8 12  material plastic`

Now I want to search this table for the properties, like choosing all entries where **color** is **blue**:

`select entry_id from table where property = 'color' and value = 'blue'`

So far, so good. But how do I expand the query when I have multiple conditions? For example I want to search for all entries where **color** is **blue** and **shape** is **circle**. Right now I'd achieve this with unions:

`select entry_id from table where property = 'color' and value = 'blue'

union

select entry_id from table where property = 'shape' and value = 'circle'`

this obviously gets ugly the more properties I want to look for. And I think it's not very fast, too. Is there are more elegant way to do this? The reason for this table is, that I have objects with metadata which can be set by the user.

Thank you!

Comment: To get a godd performace, doesnt matter what solution you take, You have to create a index on (entry_id, property, value). If this triple isnt already a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?

```
select 
  distinct e1.entry_id 
from 
 table e1 
inner join
  table e2 on e1.entry_id=e2.entry_id 
where 
  e1.property='color' and 
  e1.value='blue' and 
  e2.property='shape' and 
  e2.value='circle'
```

Comment: I'd select DISTINCT entry_id's

Comment: you would need to do select distinct, ID 12 would come back twice, his union statement is discarding the duplicate.

Comment: i modified it so it'd select out what he asked for not what his previous query returned (hope this is what he wanted)

Comment: thanks! I think I'll try it this way and make some perfomance tests with all the solutions provided

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.entry_id
FROM   table a INNER JOIN table b USING (entry_id)
WHERE  a.property = 'color' AND a.value = 'blue'
   AND b.property = 'shape' AND b.value = 'circle'
```

Comment: Thanks, and does this perform well?

Comment: @acme To get a godd performace, You have to create a index on (entry_id, property, value). If this triple isnt already a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can trick MySQL into building a hash table in lieu of `union` or `or`:

```
select distinct
    entry_id
from
    table t
    inner join 
        (select 'shape' as property, 'circle' as value
         union all
         select 'color' as property, 'blue' as value) s on
        t.property = s.property
        and t.value = s.value
```

You can also try an `exists`:

```
select distinct 
    entry_id
from
    table t
where
    exists (select 1 from 
                (select 'shape' as property, 'circle' as value
                 union all
                 select 'color' as property, 'blue' as value) s
           where 
               s.property = t.property
               and s.value = t.value)
```

Using one of these two methods, you can append as many search conditions as your little heart desires by simply tacking on another `union all` to the `s` subquery.

Comment: and how can I achieve a "like" search on the fields with these meethods?

Comment: These should actually be very performant. As for the `like`, you could do `where t.property like '%' + s.property + '%'` if you felt so inclined. It's just a join condition, so go nuts with it if you need to.